# Check for changes in NSManagedObject's object graph

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

When working with NSManagedObjects, is there a way to know if the object itself or any of its referenced objects changed without having to iterate over all desired objects to check? If i call `hasChanges` or `changedValues`, those properties only reflect changes on the object itself, but not if any values in the objects referenced objects changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to listen for a notification.  If you listen for `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` you will receive a notification every time something has changed.

As you can guess, this is chatty.

You can also ask the `NSManagedObjectContext` for all objects that have changed and then filter through that array with a `NSPredicate` to check for the object you care about.

Comment: Thanks the second solution was usable for my case. Don't really like it too much, but it works.